# Tried to open external harddrive img file

Tags: linux, centos, files, filesystems

[image]I have an img file, which is packaged in a centos virtual machine. I don't know how to open it. Now I have "parted" it on another machine and found that it is an lvm structure. The question now is how do I mount the lvm part inside the .img file inside my external USB drive

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618). [Edit] and post text.

Answer (score 3):

Use `losetup` to associate the image file with a free `/dev/loopN` device:

```
losetup -P -f /mnt/usb/vdisk1.img
```

This will report the name of the actual loop device used: if there are no other loop devices in use, it will report `/dev/loop0` and so you will be able to access the partitions within the image as `/dev/loop0p1`, `/dev/loop0p2` and `/dev/loop0p3`. If the reported loop device name is different, the names of the partition devices will also vary accordingly.

(With the following examples, I assume that the loop device was `/dev/loop0`.)

Since the first partition is flagged `bios_grub`, it probably contains just raw embedded BIOS GRUB code, not a filesystem. Therefore there will be no need to inspect it.

If you need to access the second partition in the image, you will be able to do it now:

```
mkdir /mnt/image/partition2
mount /dev/loop0p2 /mnt/image/partition2
```

For the LVM in the third partition, first run `vgscan` to ensure the LVM PV is detected, then `vgchange -ay` to activate it:

```
vgscan
vgchange -ay
```

If these commands report a `duplicate volume group` error, then the VG on the image has the same name as an already-activated VG in the local system, and the VG on the image will not activate unless the name conflict is removed first. To rename a VG when you have two VGs with the same name, you'll need the VG UUID: use `vgs -o +VG_UUID` to view the VG UUIDs, then use `vgrename` to rename the duplicate, using the UUID to identify the VG to rename. Then run `vgchange -ay` to try and activate it again.

When `vgchange -ay` runs without errors, use `lvs` to view the names of the logical volumes on the image. Now you will be able to mount them using `mount /dev/<VG>/<LV> <mountpoint>` as usual.

---

To disconnect the image after you're done with it:

- first unmount all filesystems you've mounted from the image
- then deactivate the volume group with `vgchange -an <VG>`
- finally detach the loop device: `losetup --detach /dev/loop0`

Now you will be able to unmount the USB drive without `device is busy` errors.

Answer (score 1):

Use `losetup` to create a [loop device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device) from the image

```
losetup -P -f /mnt/usb/vdisk1.img
```

the content of the image will be available as `/dev/loopX`, if the LVM structure on it isn't auto activated use `vgs` and/or `vgscan` to get name of the volume group, activate it using `vgchange -ay <name>` and then mount the logical volumes (you can get list of them using `lvs` and mount them using `mount /dev/<vgname>/<lvname> <mountpoint>`).